# IntelliJ IDEA 12 duplicate class R.java and BuildConfig.java

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I use Eclipse for android development and trying to use IntelliJ. I have successfully run the application once. But now, I couldn't seem to rebuild the example Hello World application. What am I missing here? The R.java is not rebuilding anymore. Here is a screenshot of the errors.

[image]

And here is my setting

[image]

Comment: I am having the exact same issue - I will let you know if I find anything. IntelliJ is by far the best Android IDE, but this is becoming a nightmare.

Comment: This happened to me today. Turned out I had been sloppy and had duplicate dependencies. After removing the extra dependency, everything worked just fine again...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This happened to me because I've marked source folders incorrectly.
Under project settings once you click on particular module, Just check whether you have Mark any additional folders as source folders.
Check the screenshot, By default it should be something like below, All mark as buttons should be unchecked

[image]

By mistake I've checked Mark as: "Source" button and I got this error. Just uncheck it.

Comment: This did the trick, some how the R folder under target was being included, therefore duplicated class error. Thanks my friend!

Comment: Excellent. That got me out of a hole too. Trying to get intellij to pick up the raw sources for class inspection got me here - I keep getting a decompiled source for stuff like java.lang.string.

Comment: Much better than my answer :D Thank you for resolving this issue properly!

Comment: Thank you! I've been banging my head against the wall on this one!

Comment: helps me a lot! you save my day!

Answer (score 2):

R and BuildConfig are autogenerated by the android build system. Maybe you somehow copied an autogenerated version of your eclipse project into the idea project and then idea generated second ones. By default, idea will use a folder called gen for these files which is marked as a source folder. Make sure there are no other source folder containings these files.

You can quickly find classes by pressing Ctrl+N and starting to type the name of the class. If you find duplicate results, delete any of them and let idea regenerate the correct ones.

Comment: this is not an eclipse project. i have started this from the IntelliJ wizard. sigh.. thanks anyway

Comment: Great comment. IntelliJ creates Android projects with the paths set to .idea/gen (etc) by default. So if you change them in the Project Settings, you need to delete .idea/res or you will have duplicate R and BuildConfig class definitions.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you may not like my answer, but my project is due yesterday and I don't have time to check every setting to fix the issue.

The way I resolved it is to re-create a new project, only copying the src, res, lib etc across. This was painfully difficult and presents other issues (manifest files and run/debug configs) , but proved relatively short as opposed to creating a new project ANYWAY and sifting through build options that may or may not be valid.

I encountered the problem while trying to add the KSOAP2 libs to the IDEA project, and although KSOAP has nothing to do with the problem, I may have imported them in the incorrect manner the first time and created extra self referential dependancies. This makes the most sense, but trying to figure out how to undo it would be next to impossible.

Comment: Thanks, I am really frustrated with IntelliJ. This is my first try using it as most of the people says its really the best Android IDE out there. I don't know if you have seen my g+ posts regarding this and I even encountered a series of other issues after recreating the project. I will accept this as answer since there is really no real answer. I will be sticking with eclipse for the time being.

Comment: I share your pain, it is something awful to get stuck in a project with an uncooperative IDE. But I have to say it really is a great IDE when you get to understand the quirks. Once I restarted the project I had all sorts of headaches with SVN, but at least the IDE has SVN built in.

The thing I hate the most about Eclipse is the strings.xml. I find it so difficult when I am busy in the UI and now I need to go create a string, save the file, open a new window... My current project is IDEA's 2nd chance and I have to say, even for it's difficulties, I will go back.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to delete the r and buildconfig files from the com/x/x folder under android -> java

that fixed it for me.